# Does the text-to-speech demo on gcp work for SSML?

Tags: user-interface, google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech, gtts

I have been trying out the google cloud gui demo . I want to use native pronounciation of a word from an english speaker.
For example -

```
<speak>The french word for cat is <lang xml:lang="fr-FR">chat</lang></speak>
```

Unfortunately , the french pronounciation is not correct when i use an english speaker and vice-versa. This is an example from google-cloud tts documentation only .
Am I missing something here or are `<voice>` and `<lang>` ssml tags not accessible in the demo , since rest of the tags like `<break>` , `<emphasis>` etc seem to work .

Here is the json of the above query -

```
{
  "audioConfig": {
    "audioEncoding": "LINEAR16",
    "effectsProfileId": [
      "small-bluetooth-speaker-class-device"
    ],
    "pitch": 0,
    "speakingRate": 1
  },
  "input": {
    "ssml": "<speak>The french word for cat is chat</speak>"
  },
  "voice": {
    "languageCode": "en-US",
    "name": "en-US-Neural2-A"
  }
}
```

in the ssml field clearly the lang tag is not reflected.